# Uwp 8.1 Full Screen C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to know how to force UWP App for windows 8.1 On windows 10 in full screen mode.

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

Does not work for me, I have not method `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode`.

I tried also to get View, but I have not method `TryToFullScreen`, as explained in microsoft guidelines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no API to get windows 8.1 app in full screen mode. [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getforcurrentview.aspx) are windows 10 APIs. It is strongly recommended porting the existing project to Universal Windows Platform.

But If you really want to use the new features in Windows 8.1 app,there is an ugly workaround to get access to these APIs(using reflection):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
...
var view = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
var runtimeMethods = view.GetType().GetRuntimeMethods();// get the runtime methods
var tryEnterFullScreenMode = runtimeMethods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "TryEnterFullScreenMode");
tryEnterFullScreenMode?.Invoke(view, null);//invoke the tryEnterFullScreenMode method.
```

Comment: So, is this answer an [acceptable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ?

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```